# Jenkins Parallel builds with different parametrized input parameters

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I currently have a Freestyle parametrized job, Job A (takes in 5 input parameters) and it is triggered remotely by an API. Whenever a user sends a request to the API with some input paramters, an equivalent build is triggered with a specific set of build parameter values.

Therefore, 1 API request = 1 Job A with 1 set of parameters. One more point to note is that I will never know the job build parameter values beforehand since they coming in from users' API requests.

I have 6 build executors on Jenkins meaning I can run 6 jobs in parallel. However, if the load to the API increases say 200 requests per minute... that means that 194 jobs will be queued while only 6 are executed.

I want to achieve more parallelism i.e. a scenario where multiple parallel and **independent** instances of the parametrized Job A are running with their **respective (different) sets of parameters**.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what more parallelism you are trying to achieve. 6 executors will run the incoming jobs in 6 parallel processes. Describe your problem more.

Comment: I wanted to explore any plugins which can trigger Job A in parallel on each of the executors. @MykhayloKopytonenko

Comment: Have you considered using Jenkins pipelines extension? It allows to parallelize jobs with `parallel` command. Here is an example: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel